# Extracting a month from date using lubridate - renaming problem

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I have this dataframe

```
df=data.frame("temp"=c(60.80,46.04,26.96,24.98),"humid"=c(93.79,53.33,50.34,54.65),"wind_speed"=c(40.27,39.12,14.96, 13.81), "date" =c("2013-01-31","2013-01-31","2013-02-02", "2013-02-02"))

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%Y-%m-%d")

View(df)
# after the code above, I need to do smth else with my data, then I transform the dataframe.
df_mod<- cbind(df[4], stack(df[1:3]))

df_mod$date<- as.data.frame(df_mod$date) %>%
  mutate(Month = lubridate::month(df_mod$date, label = TRUE))

View(df_mod)
```

I want to create a column named  'Month'.   the code above does what I want however, it renames my 'date' column as 'date$df_mod$date' and my new month column becomes named as 'date$Month'.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `as.data.frame(df_mod$date)`, use `select(date)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df_mod %>%
  select(date) %>% 
  mutate(Month = month(date, label = TRUE))
```

Or combine the select and mutate steps using [`transmute()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html):

```
df_mod %>%
  transmute(
    date,
    Month = month(date, label = TRUE)
  )
```

Or use `mutate()` with `.keep = "used"`:

```
df_mod %>%
  mutate(
    Month = month(date, label = TRUE),
    .keep = "used"
  )
```

Output from all three approaches:

```
         date Month
1  2013-01-31   Jan
2  2013-01-31   Jan
3  2013-02-02   Feb
4  2013-02-02   Feb
5  2013-01-31   Jan
6  2013-01-31   Jan
7  2013-02-02   Feb
8  2013-02-02   Feb
9  2013-01-31   Jan
10 2013-01-31   Jan
11 2013-02-02   Feb
12 2013-02-02   Feb
```